# How to resolve Jquery Mobile back transitions flickers page and restores it?

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition, flicker

I transit from a Jquery Mobile page to other using $.mobile.changePage but coming back to the original flickers it before restoring its size,i.e. slightly expands and comes back to normal code size.How to resolve this,help me with a snippet or example.Thanks a lot.